# ADMU3011E: Server launched but failed initialization when set generic VM args

Tags: websphere

I was facing a `Java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space` in the Websphere console.

To resolve that I have put the following generic VM args

`-Xms512m –Xmx1024m -XX:PermSize=512m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m`

But after that I cannot start the server, it is showing

`ADMU3011E: Server launched but failed initialization.`

I cannot open the WAS Admin Console to revert the chnages back.
What can I do in this case?

Comment: have you checked the server logs? The SystemOut and SystemErr logs should point you somewhere.

Comment: I have cleared the SystemOut.log. But now no error trace are logging in to this file. Not sure why.

Comment: nothing in the native_* log files either? You can always edit the configuration file directly. look for server.xml under WAS_HOME/AppServer/profiles/<PROFILE>/config/cells/...

Comment: Yes. The server.xml. I have modified the parameters and worked. If you need, put as answer and I will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referring to the valuable comments, I came to the following solution:

Go to
`${PROFILE_HOME}/config/cells/${CELL}/nodes/${NODE}/servers/${SERVER}`
and modify `server.xml`

Removed generic JVM arguments
`-Xms512m –Xmx1024m -XX:PermSize=512m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m`

Then started the server again.